# Connect to Internet using Network Manager in a script or program

Tags: kde, wifi, networkmanager

I want to connect to Internet using wireless automatically(using a script or program)

Currently,I do the following steps to connect to Internet by wlan:

1. Select the wlan access point,
2. Then KDE desktop will prompt a authentication windows to input my root password
3. Then open my browser. A webpage from the access point server is shown. The page is for me to input the username and password I have bought
4. Then I submit the form waiting for response
5. Last, connected.

I am wondering if I can have all those steps performed in a program or a script.

For step 3 and 4, I think I can use **curl** to POST data.

But prior to this step, how can I do the the following:

1. select wlan access point in KDE Network Manager(any command or library?).
2. input the password KDE prompted for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkManager provides a command line interface in the application `nmcli`.

This can be used to inspect and initiate/terminate connection, but as I understand it cannot be used to configure new connections.

Answer (score 2):

The way these ["captive portal"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) WLANs work, two things are to be discerned:

1. **local network connection**, which enables you to access the captive portal (web form) but nothing further
2. connecting to the **internet**, unlocked using the captive portal

where (1) works as always and (2) needs something to be done, i.e., entering a password in some web form.  As you already noticed, (2) can be solved using `curl`.  So what's missing is having NetworkManager auto-connect - to get (1). [See here for NetworkManager's ability to auto-connect on boot without a user logged in or some wallet unlocked](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Automatically_connect_on_boot), where [this bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204340) about `knetworkmanager`s missing ability to configure the auto-connect thing is mentioned *which has since been marked "resolved", so you might want to try finding some preference in `knetworkmanager`s options*.

Another possibility I found useful is that in some situations, the (1) step [combined with a VPN connection does the trick](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Use_dispatcher_to_connect_to_a_vpn_after_a_network-connection_is_established), too.  So if this is the case, you can save yourself the hassle of `curl`ing the web form. (Which could probably also be done using the dispatcher, see the last link.)